# Editing binary PowerShell module in Visual Studio. How to add multi-line comments for cmdlets?

Tags: syntax, comments

I'm taking over someone else's binary PowerShell module for our products. I'm new to VS, but not to PowerShell.

I'm trying to find info on how to add comment-based help to the cmdlets, but not finding the syntax for doing so within Visual Studio (in my case, 2013 Premium). My BingFoo is failing, and I'm not coming up with anything in online searches. Is anyone aware of a site/article/page that shows how to do it?

I also need to put comments above each parameter. For example, I want

```
   (some syntax here)
   [Parameter(Mandatory = false)]
   public string WiFi { get; set; }
```

to result in the following in the cmdlet when viewing in PowerShell:

```
   # Whether this subnet is on Wi-Fi
   [Parameter(Mandatory = false)]
   [string] $WiFi
```

Answer (score 0):

Several people told me it can't be done. So I ended up just using the [PowerShell Cmdlet Help Editor](https://pscmdlethelpeditor.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex. Made life a LOT easier.